# How can I use "PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser" to get the contents of an <h1></h1> tag?

Tags: php, html-parsing

I'm new to PHP =) Right now I am using PHP includes for my site template. I have my header, containing all my `<head></head>` info. What I want to do is write a code that will take the contents of the `<h1></h1>` tag from the page, and echo it into the `<title></title>` tag in my header.php include.

I got the PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser from here: [http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/][1], and I found a code (I forget where in all my googling) that goes like this:

```
<?php
$url = (!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS'])) ? "https://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] : "http://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$html = file_get_html('http://www.myurl.com/');
foreach($html->find('#content h1') as $element){
    echo $element->plaintext;}
?>
```

That I think is supposed to echo the h1 tag contents? Like I said, I'm new to PHP and I only know the basics, and I don't know really know any OOP (yet), so I'm sorry if I'm asking a dumb question.

It looks like it's getting the current page, then putting the contents of the h1 tag into the variable $element, and then echoing it. But nothing happens when I put it into my page. Can anyone help me with what I'm doing wrong? Thank you for reading!! =)

EDIT: Here's my HTML

From the header.php file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />

<?php
/* current page url */
function curPageURL() {
 $pageURL = 'http';
 if ($_SERVER["HTTPS"] == "on") {$pageURL .= "s";}
 $pageURL .= "://";
 if ($_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] != "80") {
  $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].":".$_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
 } else {
  $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
 }
 return $pageURL;
}
?>

<?php include '/home/dreami14/public_html/simplehtmldom/simplehtmldom/simple_html_dom.php' ?>

<title>
<?php
$url = curPageURL();
$html = file_get_html($url);
foreach($html->find('#main h1') as $element){
    echo $element->plaintext;}
?></title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/stylesheet.css" />
</head>
<body>
```

From test.php:

```
<?php include '/home/dreami14/public_html/design/includes/head.php' ?>

<div id="main">
<h1>This should be the title</h1>
<p>Blah blah</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

I don't get any errors, but my `<title></title>` is empty.

Edit to add: also, I echoed $url in the document itself so I know that part is working

Comment: Looks like an infinite loop to me. In order to display the whole page you are calling the same URL inside your script, which then tries to build the whole page, which again calls the URL.... got my point?

Comment: Thanks Felix- so when I do this:[[[ $html = file_get_html($url); ]]], is that the part that is calling up the whole page? Is there another way to do this that you know of?

Comment: Simple HTML DOM parser - good script.

Your "pattern" - bad idea.

Answer (score 3):

You're not saying how your HTML is structured, but if you want to find the `h1` with the ID `content` you need to use

```
foreach($html->find('h1#content') as $element){
```

the way you are doing it right now, it says "find any `h1` element *within* another element with the ID `content`".

Comment: Thanks for your answer, that is what I wanted it to do. I tried just now a few different ways- giving the h1 tag an id of "title" and changing the php code to h1#title, but it still isn't echoing anything :(

Answer (score 0):

I would restructure your code a little. Basically, you are trying to get the content in `h1` before it is populated. In your `test.php` I would define an array with meta data and then include the header.
Like so:

`test.php`

```
<?php 
$meta = array();
$meta['title'] = "This should be the title";

include '/home/dreami14/public_html/design/includes/head.php' 

?>

<div id="main">
<h1><?php echo $meta['title'] ?></h1>
<p>Blah blah</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

`head.php`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
   <title>
 <?php echo (isset($meta) && isset($meta['title'])) ? $meta['title'] : "Default title"; ?>
   </title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/stylesheet.css" />
</head>
<body>
```

---

But if you start to do more complicated stuff, you should have a look at the [Model-View-Controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) design pattern and e.g. the [Zend framework](http://framework.zend.com/), which implements it.

Answer (score 0):

I thinks it's the way, only print child content:

```
html = file_get_html($url);
foreach($ret->children as $child) {  
   echo $child;
}
```